# app crashing with "Called From Wrong Thread Exception"

Tags: android, handler, timertask

I added this part of the code in my `onCreate()` method and it crashes my app.
need help.

**LOGCAT:**

```
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread 
that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

**CODE:**

```
final TextView timerDisplayPanel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            timerInt++;
            Log.d("timer", "timer");
            timerDisplayPanel.setText("Time ="+ timerInt +"Sec");
        }
    },10, 1000);
```

Comment: (I have no idea, how to use a handler.)- I read somewhere that I need  to use a handler object.\

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
Only the UI thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

You are trying to change the text of the UI element in Non UI Thread, so it gives exception.Use `runOnUiThread`

```
 Timer t = new Timer();
 t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
 public void run() {
        timerInt++;
        Log.d("timer", "timer");

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                timerDisplayPanel.setText("Time =" + timerInt + "Sec");
            }
        });

    }
}, 10, 1000);
```