# Function and Runnable Working at the Same Time (How To?) (Android, Java)

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable

I have an Android app that after pressing a **button** starts a **function** (outside onCreate()). This function changes a **global String variable** 5 times using a **for** loop. I want to **see every variable** shown on the screen (i.e. in a TextView). I understood I have to use a **Runnable** and a **Handler**, but..

in **MainActivity (extends Activity) / onCreate()**:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        handler.post(timedTask);
        Start();
    }
});
```

**Start()** runs, but nothing went on the screen until it had **finished**.

In **MainActivity (extends Activity):**

```
private Runnable timedTask = new Runnable()
{
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
          textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          textView1.append(globalMessage);
          handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
      }};
```

in **MainActivity (extends Activity) / Start():**

```
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    ...
    globalMessage = message[j];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're accessing variable from different threads. You should declare it as `volatile`.

So you want your `timedTask` to display 5 values of globalMessage?

Make sure to synchronized timedTask with your loop so that after every modification timedTask executes.

```
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    ...
    globalMessage = message[j];
    ...// wait sometime here or make sure it is a long operation that is enough for synchronization
}
```

**EDIT**

Your `handler.post` might not be starting runnable immediately. You can start your runnable yourself:

```
(new Thread(timedTask)).start(); // instead of handler.post
```

Or do it the easiest way: just update text in your for loop in the same thread.

Comment: I already have a **Thread.sleep()**, it's actually before it, that's not the problem. See, I have String message[] = {"alfa", "beta", "mom", "dad", "gama"}; and after the **Start()** function finishes the app starts spamming **"gamma"**, but there's **no sign** of the others before it. That means the whole **Runnable** starts **after the function** when I want it to run **parallel** with it.

Comment: handler.post(timedTask); - does it start execute runnable immediately?  if it is scheduled but not started immediately - then possibly this is your case

Comment: The handler.post() function is called when pressing the button and right after it Start() is called. The screen changes after the Start() function ends. How do I start it?

Comment: sorry, I meant does method handler.post starts your runnable immediately? The problem should be there

Comment: I don't know when it starts, but I think after Start(), how do  I change that? How do I make it start with the function?

Comment: I tried what you edited, the app **crashes** on the button press.

E/AndroidRuntime(19011): java.lang.NullPointerException

this is part ot the **logcat**
and if I remove `textView1.append(globalMessage);`
this line, it works, but of course nothing happens.

i changed **append** with **setText** but now it says 
E/AndroidRuntime(19229): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: ok, then the easiest way to do this is to set text in you for loop. I don't think you need another thread this case

Comment: But that doesn't work! The fact that it doesn't work made me try the Runnable in the first place. Nothing changes, except the last output, maybe because OnClick is in the OnCreate, and usually everything is shown on the screen after OnCreate ends

Answer (score 0):

I got it! The trick is **putting** all the **code from the method/function to the Runnable**, then everything is working fine and **every text is updating** on the spot. So this code:

```
private Runnable timedTask = new Runnable()
{
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
          textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          textView1.append(globalMessage);
          handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
      }};
```

becomes:

```
private Runnable timedTask = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
        ...
        globalMessage = message[j];
        textView1.setText(globalMessage);
        ...
        }
    }
};
```

**There are some things I changed though:**

1. Thanks to **Tala** I changed `handler.post(timedTask);` with `Thread thread1 = new Thread(timedTask1);` and then `thread1.start();` or simply with one line `(new Thread(timedTask)).start();`
2. I had some issues with some exceptions:

android.view.ViewRoot$ **CalledFromWrongThreadException**: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

This accured with `textView1.setText(globalMessage);` and `textView1.append(globalMessage);` and surely more methods of that type and **which are not in onCreate()**. If you want to use them out of onCreate then read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11062834/1992635) answer which suggests replacing **that line** with:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        button1.append(globalMessage);
    }
});
```

Another exception you should look out for is java.lang. **NullPointerException** which means you should initialise some variables in the current method/runnable/scope

If someone has questions: feel free to comment here!