# Unable to play video with VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to play 4 different videos(when 4 different buttons are pressed) which are in my Internal Storage of my phone .All the buttons are in `DashBoardActivity`.When  a `Button` is pressed, I start a new `VideoActivity` by creating `Intent`and placing a unique integer extra for each button click.Here is my code  in `DashBoardActivty`

```
 Button b1= findViewById(R.id.education_button);
  b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this,VideoActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(sBUTTON_,1);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Here is the code in my `VideoActivity`

```
public class VideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int j;
VideoView vid;
Uri uri;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
    Intent i = getIntent();
     j = i.getIntExtra(DashboardActivity.sBUTTON_,1);
    vid=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);

    if(j==1)
        uri=Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Movies/MoShow/Educations.mp4");

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            vid.setVideoURI(uri);
            vid.start();


        }
    });
  }
  }//end of class
```

When I install the app on physical device . I get a error

> Can't play this video

However , when I see the `logcat` the error it is showing is

> ? E/ViewRootImpl: Accessibility content change on non-UI thread. Future Android versions will throw an exception.
>                                                  android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

I am confused whether this is a video format(codec) problem (as I see "can't play this video" on my phone screen) . I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062818/app-crashing-with-called-from-wrong-thread-exception)  post to solve

> CalledFromWrongThreadException

but I am getting the same error.Below is my XML file for `VideoActivity`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
            tools:context="com.example.srini.animtest.VideoActivity">


<VideoView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/video"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you logged and tested what does uri you are generating is?

Comment: and have you taken permission of read files from app?

Comment: @Rizwanatta thanks for the suggestion. It worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
vid.setVideoURI(uri);

vid.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

        vid.start();

        }
    });
```